# My excel macro generates errors inconsistently

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am working on a macro to automate some web browser stuff and there is an intermittent runtime error 91 "object variable or with block variable not set". I have been playing around with how I declare and create my browser object but nothing is working.

```
Sub Morning_Script()
Dim WebBrowser As Object
Set WebBrowser = New InternetExplorerMedium
WebBrowser.Visible = True
WebBrowser.navigate "www.google.com"

While WebBrowser.Busy = True
    DoEvents
Wend

WebBrowser.document.getElementById("lst-ib").Value = "test"
'WebBrowser.document.getElementById("verify").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
'WebBrowser.document.getElementById("institution").Value = "xxx"
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Clear
'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Clear
End Sub
```

The URL has been changed to a public website and the form entry has been commented out for now.

Comment: It's possible you need to add a wait before trying to access the form elements.

Comment: wait for what? I already wait for the browser to load.

Comment: A lot of current web content is dynamic and is loaded/created once the page has loaded (where "loaded" means all of the source has been delivered but does not necessarily mean the page is complete).  Many pages fetch additional content via scripting in order to construct the page.  You are only testing for "busy", which for many pages is only part of the process of getting to an interactive state.

Comment: ah, thank you I'll try a 3ish second wait after the page is no longer busy

Comment: that did it, even with just a 1 second wait, no more error 91!

Answer (score 0):

If you would prefer to avoid fixed timers, try this one:

```
Dim objElement As Object: Set objElement = Nothing
While objElement Is Nothing
    Set objElement = WebBrowser.document.getElementById("lst-ib")
    DoEvents
Wend
objElement.Value = "test"
```

If you would like to refer to verify and institution to, you would have to implement this scheme for them, too and wait until all three variables are non-nothing. You may also want to set a timeout or maximum retry number if there is a really great number of pages to download.